# ラジオボタンの選択状況の可視化について

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

**現在の状況**

1. 複数の画像を表示し、それらをラジオボタンとして機能させています。
2. ラジオボタン自体の`<input type='radio'>`は`{display: none;}`で非表示にして、`<ravel>`で囲まれた画像がボタンとして機能しています。
3. 現在クリックしても、ユーザー視点でクリックしたかが分からない。

**実装したいこと**

1. 画像が選択された際に選択状況が分かるように、選択された画像が半透明になるような動きを実現したい。
2. ラジオボタンのため、別の画像をクリックし直した際はその他は通常表示に戻したい。

PHP、laravel初学者で、アプリを作成しておりますが、この実装ができません。
今の所JavaScriptを用いて実装したいことの1は実現できそうなのですが、2で行うための記述がわかりません。
どなたかご教授いただけますと幸いです。

**HTML**

```
<div class='select_seed'>
  <h1>型犬の中から選ぶ</h1>
    <ul>  
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='1'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/smooth-chihuahua.jpg') }}" alt='スムースコートチワワ'><p>スムースコートチワワ</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='2'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/chihuahua.jpg') }}" alt='チワワ'><p>チワワ</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='3'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/tea-poodle.jpg') }}" alt='ティーカッププードル'><p>ティーカッププードル</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='4'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/toy-poodle.jpg') }}" alt='トイプードル'><p>トイプードル</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='5'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/man-terrier.jpg') }}" alt='トイマンチェスターテリア'><p>トイマンチェスターテリア</p></li></label>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='6'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/papillon.jpg') }}" alt='パピヨン'><p>パピヨン</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='7'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/pomeranian.jpg') }}" alt='ポメラニアン'><p>ポメラニアン</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='8'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/mameshiba.jpg') }}" alt='豆柴'><p>豆柴</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='9'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/maltese.jpg') }}" alt='マルチーズ'><p>マルチーズ</p></li></label>
      <label><li><input type='radio' name='seed'  value='10'>
      <img class='photo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/y-terrier.jpg') }}" alt='ヨークシャーテリア' ><p>ヨークシャーテリア</p></li></label>
    </ul>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: ][1]]

Comment: コードのスクリーンショットかコードの一部を編集して追加することは可能ですか？

Comment: ＠su3158
htmlのコードの画像を追記させていただきました！

Comment: ソースコードなどの文字情報は、スクリーンショットではなく **文字のまま** 質問に含めてもらった方が良いのかなと思います。(回答する際に引用がし辛いため)

Comment: @cubic ソースコードの記述とサイト表示を追記させていただきました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私が現在使用しているコードを上のコードみたいに当てはめて変えてみました
ただ画像をアップロードしてスニペットで使う方法が分からなかったので全て文字になっていますが
そこを`<img>`に変更していただければ使用できると思います

ただその際にCSSのサイズなどの変更、色の変化などはしないといけないでしょうけども

この様なコードになりました、参考になると思います

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nordio {
  display: none;
}

.pad {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 4em 0 0;
}

.coolrdio {
  width: 150%;
  margin: 0.7em;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  border: 1px #aaf3ed solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.coolrdio:hover {
  background: #47e4d7;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #5555ff;
}

.seach-input {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}

.seach-label {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.selectbox {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
}

.selectlabel {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<label class="inputlabel">犬を選んでください</label>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="pad">
      <input id="test1" name="dog" type="radio" class="selectbox nordio" value="1" checked="" required="">
      <label class="selectlabel coolrdio" for="test1">犬</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="pad">
      <input id="test2" name="dog" type="radio" class="selectbox nordio" value="2" required="">
      <label class="selectlabel coolrdio" for="test2">犬</label>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="pad">
      <input id="test3" name="dog" type="radio" class="selectbox nordio" value="3" required="">
      <label class="selectlabel coolrdio" for="test3">犬</label>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="pad">
      <input id="test4" name="dog" type="radio" class="selectbox nordio" value="4" required="">
      <label class="selectlabel coolrdio" for="test4">犬</label>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="pad">
      <input id="test5" name="dog" type="radio" class="selectbox nordio" value="5" required="">
      <label class="selectlabel coolrdio" for="test5">犬</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: htmlのinputにchecked="" required=""等の記載をしてみたのですが動きません。　lavelの位置はliタグの前に持ってくると不具合が起こりますでしょうか

Comment: @k0727 <label>の中に<li>要素を入れるのは推奨されていません[こちらに詳しくあります](http://www.tohoho-web.com/html/label.htm)

Comment: ありがとうございます！こちらのコードを元に記述のし直しをしてみます！

Comment: @k0727 出来ましたか？

Comment: 遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません！　実装できました！ありがとうございます！とても勉強にもなり大変感謝しております